# Drawer Layout on top of action bar?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have created the navigation drawer just as explained by the google

[Creating a Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

How can I make it overlap the action bar just like the google play store or gmail android apps.

Any idea about that?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // Set the adapter for the list view
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.list_item1, mPlanetTitles));
    // Set the list's click listener
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.string.action_settings, R.string.action_settings) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("OPEN");
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("CLOSE");
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}
```

Activity XML

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.drawermenu.MainActivity" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#111"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: use toolbar. and refer google io 2014 app from github for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a ToolBar instead of the usual actionbar, the ToolBar goes as any view in your layout, like that:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id=”@+id/my_toolbar”
    android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
    android:layout_width=”match_parent” />
```

And then you can set it as your action bar if you want, or deal with it directly

Comment: Thanx thats what I needed. But I am getting the activity name in the background. How do I remove that?

Comment: have your content to be below the ToolBar, maybe in linear layout or using "below" in a relative layout

Answer (score 0):

The question has been answered. But still I would like to post the whole answer for other users who face difficulty to do so.

Here are the screenshots of the final solution

[image: Toolbarr]

[image: Navigation Drawer overlapping action Bar/ toolbar]

1. Java Class

   ```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private String[] mPlanetTitles = { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
       private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
       private ListView mDrawerList;
       private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
   setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
   getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
   mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
   mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

   // Set the adapter for the list view
   mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
           R.layout.list_item1, mPlanetTitles));
   // Set the list's click listener
   mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
   mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
           R.string.action_settings, R.string.action_settings) {

       /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
       public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
           super.onDrawerClosed(view);
           getSupportActionBar().setTitle("OPEN");
           invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                       // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
       }

       /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
       public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
           super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
           getSupportActionBar().setTitle("CLOSE");
           invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                       // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
       }
   };

   // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
   mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
   }

   private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
       ListView.OnItemClickListener {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position,
           long id) {

       TextView t = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvExtra);
       Log.e("text", t.getText().toString());
       startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
               JavaDrawerActivity.class));
   }
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content
   // view
   // boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
   // menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
   return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
   return true;
   }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
   // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
   // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
   int id = item.getItemId();
   if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
       return true;
   }
   if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
       return true;
   }
   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
   mDrawerToggle.syncState();
   }

   @Override
   public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
   super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
   mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
   }

   }
   ```
2. XML

   ```
     <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      tools:context="com.example.drawermenu.MainActivity" >

     <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/content_frame"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:background="#FFFFFF"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" >

       <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
           android:id="@+id/toolbar"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:background="#2196F3"
           android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" >
       </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textColor="#000000"
           android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
           android:text="@string/hello_world" />
   </RelativeLayout>
   </FrameLayout>

       <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

   <ListView
       android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
       android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
       android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imageView1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
      </LinearLayout>

   </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
   ```
3. Set a style for activity

   ```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
   <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
   <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
   </style>
   ```
4. Finally set the style in manifest

   ```
     <activity
       android:name=".MainActivity"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   ```

And Voila you are all set!!!